# How to make a Post request in Angular (Post failed on my code need to know why)

Tags: angular, typescript, post, cors

I'm trying to create simple form with Angular which will store 3 fields on a SQLite DB.

My Backend runs fine, I can post, get and do everything on Swagger but when I try it with my Angular page, it doesn't work.

This is what I have so far:

HTML Component Form

```
<div class="align-center">
  <h2>Bem Vindo à Prevenir Assistencial</h2>
  <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input
      placeholder="Nome"
      type="text"
      name="nome"
      [(ngModel)]="user.nome"
    />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input
      placeholder="Email"
      type="email"
      name="email"
      [(ngModel)]="user.email"
    />
    <label>Telefone</label>
    <input
      placeholder="Telefone"
      type="text"
      name="telefone"
      [(ngModel)]="user.telefone"
    />
    <div class="btn-div">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="login-btn">
        Acessar
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

TS component (I left all the commented code to show what I have tried)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { User } from '../Interfaces/user';
import { RegistroService } from '../services/registro.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.scss']
})
export class LandingPageComponent {


  user: User = {
    nome: null,
    email: null,
    telefone: null
  };

  // user = {
  //   nome: null,
  //   email: null,
  //   telefone: null
  // };

  constructor(private registroService: RegistroService, private toastr: ToastrService)
  {
  }

  
  // onSubmit(user: any): void {

  //   user = user.trim();
  //   if(!user) {return;}
  //   this.registroService.addRegistro(user as any).subscribe(user => this.user = user)

  //   this.toastr.show("Obrigado pelo cadastro. Bem vindo.");
  //   console.log(user);
  // }



  // onSubmit(user: any): void {

  //   user = user.trim();
  //   if(!user) {return;}
  //   this.registroService.addRegistro({user} as any).subscribe(user => this.user = user)

  //   this.toastr.show("Obrigado pelo cadastro. Bem vindo.");
  //   console.log(user);
  // }



  // onSubmit(user: User): void {

  //   if(!user) {return;}
  //   this.registroService.addRegistro(user).subscribe(user => this.user = user)

  //   this.toastr.show("Obrigado pelo cadastro. Bem vindo.");
  //   console.log(user);
  // }



  onSubmit(user: User): void {

    this.registroService.addRegistro(user).subscribe((response: any) => {console.log(response)})

    this.toastr.show("Obrigado pelo cadastro. Bem vindo.");
  }

}
```

Service (again I left some commented code to show what I have tried)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { LandingPageComponent } from '../landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { User } from '../Interfaces/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegistroService {

  // private url = '/HotSpot';
  private url = 'localhost:5066/HotSpot';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }


    httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
      return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

        // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
        console.error(error); // log to console instead

        // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
        console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

        // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
        return of(result as T);
      };
    }



    // addRegistro(user: User): Observable<User> {
    //   return this.http.post<User>(this.url, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    //     tap((newRegistro: User) => console.log(`adicionado Registro c/ id=${newRegistro.nome}`)),
    //     catchError(this.handleError<User>('addRegistro'))
    //   );
    // }



    // addRegistro(user: any): Observable<any> {
    //   return this.http.post<any>(this.url, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    //     tap((newRegistro: any) => console.log(`adicionado Registro c/ id=${newRegistro.nome}`)),
    //     catchError(this.handleError<any>('addRegistro'))
    //   );
    // }



    // addRegistro(user: User): Observable<any> {
    //   return this.http.post<any>(this.url, user, this.httpOptions)
    // }



    addRegistro(user: User): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post<any>(this.url, user, this.httpOptions)
    }

}
```

I'm trying to understand my mistake. I'm very new to Angular and programming, so if you need more info or access to my backend code, let me know.

Any help is welcome. Thank you very much for your time.

PS:
Also, when checking DEV tools I receive this.

landing-page:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5066/HotSpot' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED       :5066/HotSpot:1

ERROR HttpErrorResponse       core.mjs:10194

I have my CORS added correctly I think, but here is my code just in case.

````
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using HotSpotAPI.Models.Data;
using HotSpotAPI.Models.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

//FIX para essa Injeção de Dependencia da Base de Dados. Override no Contexto.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HotSpot");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<HotSpotContext>(context => 
    context.UseSqlite("HotSpot"));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


// FIX para remover erro de blocked by CORS policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularOrigins",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(
                            "http://localhost:4200"
                            )
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyOrigin());

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```
````

Comment: Please note; errors should be included as text, not as a screenshot of text. Also, in English, the word is spelled I'm and and word for yourself is I (capital I).

Comment: please show your errors

Comment: Added the errors from Dev Tools in text format